# Simultaneous match in FParsec

Tags: bnf, fparsec

If I'm trying to parse the following into `lines` and `fields`.  Lines are delimited by `'\n'` and fields are delimited by `'|'`.

```
abcd|efgh|ijkl
mnopq\|rst|uvwxy
za|bcd
efg|hijk|lmnop
```

I can define the following:

```
let displayCharacter = satisfy (fun c -> ' ' <= c && c <= '~')
let escapedDC = pchar '\\' >>. displayCharacter
let test1 = 
    run (manyChars (escapedDC <|> displayCharacter)) "asdf\|efgh|ijkl"
    // Success: "asdf|efgh|ijkl"
```

But `let fields = sepBy (manyChars (escapedDC <|> displayCharacter)) (pchar '|')` cannot work to exclude the `'|'` from the field.  These delimiters are context sensitive, so I want to avoid hard-coding them into `displayCharacter` since `'|'` is a display character, but just might need escaping in certain contexts.

If I try to define a single `field` with `manyCharsTill`, then I need to account for the final element on a line with `anyOf "|\n"`, but this reads in all of the lines into one `line`.

I may have further subdelimiters beyond `'|'` that are supported in certain contexts.  For this reason, it seems messy to have to define versions of displayCharacter and escapedDC for every case.  Rather, using lookahead features seems cleaner.  Or perhaps a parser called `both` which somehow requires a match on two parsers simultaneously.

```
manyCharsSepBy (escapedDC <|> displayCharacter) (pchar '|')
```

or

```
let contextualDisplayCharacter1 = both displayCharacter (satisfy ((<>) '|'))
```

Is there an easier way to accomplish this?  Perhaps it is just my implied BNF that is flawed - that if fixed, would translate easily?

============

This is the best I can come up with, but I would like to know from the experts if it is the most flexible way.

```
let displayCharacter (excludeDelimiters : string) = satisfy (fun c -> ' ' <= c && c <= '~' && not (Seq.exists ((=) c) excludeDelimiters))
let escapedDisplayCharacter = pchar '\\' >>. displayCharacter ""

let field = 
    manyChars (escapedDisplayCharacter <|> displayCharacter "|")
```

Comment: That looks pretty good to me!  Only thing I could possibly imagine to make it more flexible would be to put `excludeDelimiters` on `field`, and possibly make it a `seq<char>` rather than `string`.